# How can I use cache to optimise google cloud build?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I want to cache the previously stored google cloud image while creating a new build for the project.
I have followed the official documentation : https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/optimize-builds/speeding-up-builds but while building it doesn't seems to be caching the data.
The yaml file I am using is:

```yaml
steps:
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
      args: ['build','--cache-from', 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/node-app:latest', '-t', 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/node-app:latest', '.']
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
      args: ['push', 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/node-app:latest']
    images:
    - 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/node-app:latest'
```

I also tried to first pull the docker image as:

```yaml
steps
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'docker pull gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/node-app:latest || exit 0']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build','--cache-from', 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/node-app:latest', '-t', 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/node-app:latest', '.']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
   args: ['push', 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/node-app:latest']
images:
    - 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/node-app:latest'
```

I checked there is image already present and it is also pulling the image but it's not caching the image.
How can I cache the image or is there any other process to do so in google cloud?

Comment: can you check this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73358406/google-cloud-build-does-not-use-cache-for-some-of-the-run-executions) once

Comment: Cool. I understand but is there any way to optimize the build process. So that it will take less time.

Comment: Have you tried Kaniko? Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59013985/18265638)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59013985/18265638) by ttfreeman

> Have you tried `Kaniko`? It can save the cache in gcr.io and and if
> you have built your Dockerfile with right steps (see
> https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/7-best-practices-for-building-containers),
> it should save you a lot of time. Here is the `cloudbuild.yaml`
> example:
>
> ```
> - name: 'gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest'  
>   args:
>   - --destination=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/image
>   - --cache=true
>   - --cache-ttl=XXh
> ```

More info: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/kaniko-cache

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `docker build --pull=false`?

In the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) the default value for `--pull` is false, but not sure why, it seems like the default in `gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker` has been changed to true probably because of [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/ef6c16e8306352db0630d0bd86e6c23059dcc353/gsutil/cloudbuild.yaml#L8).

```yaml
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['-c', 'docker pull gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/node-app:latest || exit 0']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build','--cache-from', 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/node-app:latest', '--pull', 'false', '-t', 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/node-app:latest', '.']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/node-app:latest']
images:
  - 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/node-app:latest'
```

Edit: my friend, https://github.com/abihf helped me debug this issue.